# Hint on Complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem from a past complex analysis qual, but have little idea of how to attack it. Can anybody give me a hint for this?

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $\phi(0) = 2$, $\phi(1)=1$ and $|\phi'(z)| \leq |\phi(z)|$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

a) Prove that $\phi(z) \neq 0 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

b) Prove that $\phi()$ is unique and obtain an explicit formula for it.

Thanks for any hint or advice!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\phi$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z=c$. Then there is an entire function $g$ such that $\phi (z)=(z-c)^{n} g(z)$ and $g(c) \neq 0$. The hypothesis gives $|(z-c)^{n} g'(z)+n(z-c)^{n-1} g(z)|\leq |(z-c)^{n} g(z)|$. Divide by $(z-c)^{n-1}$ and let $z \to c$ to get the  contradiction $g(c)=0$. Thus $\phi$ has no zeros. Now $\frac {\phi '} {\phi}$ is a bounded entire function and hence it is a constant. If $\frac {\phi '} {\phi}=a$ then $(e^{-az}\phi)'=0$ so $e^{-az}\phi =d$ where $d$ is a constant. From the hypothesis you find that $\phi (z)=2e^{az}$ where $a=- \ln 2$.